# Creating multiple materials in editor vs during run-time

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need multiple materials at the same time and only difference between them should be color, even texture is the same and i have to create them one by one and i wonder which way is better, to create them in editor and store them in assets or create them when game starts as temporary materials from script

Answer (score 1):

It depends mainly of when you need them.

I'm assuming you will need all of them at startup. In this case:

- Instantiating them at runtime will use more CPU for the instantiation, so the application will need more time to load.
- Having them created in the editor will need to store the data statically, so the application will occupy more memory

If you do not need all of them at startup you could start spawning them in background with a Coroutine.

```
public class MaterialSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Material[] materials;
    public int amount = 100;

    public static bool IsSpawning = false;
    private void Awake() { StartCoroutine(SpawnYourMaterial()); }

    private IEnumerator SpawnYourMaterial()
    {
        IsSpawning = true;
        int spawned = 0;
        while (spawned < amount)
        {
            //INSTANTIATE YOUR MATERIAL

            spawned++;
            yield return null;
        }

        IsSpawning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think CPU consumption is more important in my situation so I'll create them in assets

Comment: the difference is neglible performance wise. I would almost always prefer code over doing something manually, even if just for the sake of makig fewer errors, and making it easier to change stuff later

Comment: The difference is negligible both CPU wise and memory wise. I would go for the safer choice (so using memory), to avoid unnecessary complexity.  Except if you're creating a great amount of materials (thousands? probably not. most likely hundred of thousands?). In that case I would go with the coroutine implementation. But here we're moving on opinions.

Comment: I needed to load all materials at startup, so coroutines are not useful for me. Finally I wrote some code and now materials are made from script. I do so because of automatisation also i dont know how many materials are needed before the scene is loaded, so script way is better. And materials are at this moment 5(I know its too few) but during later development  their number might be increase rapidly. Thanks for ur advices